# Python-Swift interop (PythonKit) : Change Default Stdin Encoding

Tags: python, swift, tensorflow, interop, swift-pythonkit

I've imported a custom Python package into Swift using PythonKit, within a Swift Package (SPM) using XCode. The Python code at various points performs `f = open("somefile","r")`, and then `f.readline()`.

When invoked from Swift, the following error is raised from within Python :

```py
File "/Users/user/[...]/lib/python3.8/site-packages/module/unihan_variants.py", line 115, in unihan_variants_dict
    line = f.readline()

...

Python exception: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 121: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Investigating further, I see that the default stdin decoding is ascii instead of utf-8 :

```swift
let sys = Python.import("sys")
print(sys.stdin.encoding) // asciii
print(sys.stdout.encoding) // ascii
```

When I go to my original Python module, I find I can avoid the error in PythonKit by specifying `f = open("somefile","r",encoding="utf-8")`, but unfortunately I've just assumed utf-8 throughout all of my projects to date.

Is there a way to change default encoding for stdin and stdout from XCode or PythonKit?

Or is it necessary/advised to go back and specify utf-8 throughout all my Python code?

(This doesn't work) :

```swift
sys.stdin.encoding = "utf-8" //Python exception: readonly attribute: file /Users/brianparker/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Morphology-efqracfjfhxtguetmduhdszyzezb/SourcePackages/checkouts/PythonKit/PythonKit/Python.swift, line 540
```

Further notes :

- `print(platform.python_version())` returns 3.8.5
- My method for importing my Python package was by adding the path to `site-packages` within the virtualenv to `sys.path` in Swift/PythonKit
- `print(sys.getdefaultencoding())` indicates 'utf-8'. It seems weird that this differs from stdin/stdout

---

#### Update :

I've managed to get `sys.stdin.encoding` to indicate "utf-8" by setting the `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable. However the same error gets thrown at `readline()`

Answer (score 1):

Python's TextIOWrapper `open`'s default encoding isn't determined by the `sys` properties or environment variables proposed in my question. Instead, it defaults to `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`.

My Python environment shows the following, which explains why I typically don't need to specify an encoding when opening a file :

```py
>>> locale.getlocale()
('en_US', 'UTF-8')
>>> locale.getpreferredencoding(do_setlocale=False)
'UTF-8'
```

Python within Swift however does not have a default locale (at least when run on my machine):

```swift
let locale = Python.import("locale")
print(locale.getlocale()) // (None, None)
```

The following code will set the desired locale for Python within the Swift app, allowing TextIOWrapper to default to utf-8 when opening files :

```swift
let locale = Python.import("locale")
if locale.getlocale().tuple2 == (Python.None,Python.None) {
   locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, locale: PythonObject(["en_US","UTF-8"]))
}
```

Note that there's a [Python proposal](https://discuss.python.org/t/pep-597-use-utf-8-for-default-text-file-encoding/1819) from 2019 to make utf-8 TextIOWrapper's default encoding without checking `locale`, though I'm not sure if it will be adopted.